# Office 365 addin not working on IE7, working on chrome, firefox and IE8

Tags: office-365, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have a hosted addin that we developed internally. it works on chrome, firefox and IE8+, but for some reasons, the infrastructure made the default rendering for IE to be 7. Is it a limitation in office365/sharepoint with IE7?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use: `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-8"/>` in order to make the add-in render in at least IE8. Put this code in the head of your add-in page. It should work.

Comment: it\s amazing,  +1 haven't heard about this before. thanks!

Comment: Add-in developers only have to support down to IE9 (which.. from january 12th 2016 will also no longer be supported by Microsoft)

Comment: You are right if you're going to use chrome control to inherit SharePoint's design, so you'll have to follow SharePoint's rules in design. But if you will have your own design and full control of it without inheriting anything from SharePoint, then you might be asked in some cases to support browsers that SharePoint doesn't support, which is one reason I've seen some people like using add-ins like provider hosted add-in, as they will be separate sites and not limited to SharePoint's UI limitations.